# laravel validation return status 302

Tags: laravel

I have a form and I can send data through and get data in controller and see it but when use validation as below:

```
$validation= $request->validate([
  'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
   'body' => 'required',
   'message' => 'required'
  ]);
```

I have status 302 I don't know what to do

Comment: A 302 statuscode indicates a redirect. You are redirecting the user in your response.

Comment: are you using ajax also?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Http Status Code 302 means that the API (server) requests a redirect. That is the expected behavior of Laravel validation if the validation do not pass. If you want Laravel to return json instead, add the following key value pair to your **request headers**.

```
accept: application/json
```

Comment: I know I am not supposed to write +1 comments. BUT you just solved two hours of painful searching! Have a nice day :)

Comment: Just remember this does not mean your request is ajax if you need to use isAjax function also have to use X-Requested-With header.

Comment: for isAjax, the key value pair should be X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test the that route. I recommend using this.

->postJson('/api/users'); instead of just ->post('api/users')

Answer (score 0):

Insert  Accept: application/json in ajax header

```
                $.ajax({
                url:'{{route('fetchMunCit')}}' +'/'+id,
                type:'GET',
                dataType:'json',
                Accept: application/json
                    success:function(response)
```